# Loading classes at runtime from JAR file bytes

Tags: java, runtime, classloader

I have byte array of a JAR file and I need to load all the JAR classes at runtime from these bytes.
How can I do this without converting JAR bytes to a file?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You should provide a  MCVE – Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 
Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: @ThiloSchwarz – In general yes, but this question is clear without such an MCVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap that array of bytes into a `java.util.ByteArrayInputStream` and that in turn into a `java.util.jar.JarInputStream`.

The latter has methods to get one entry (most probably a class file, but also possible are some kinds of resources) after the other as an instance of `JarEntry`, and to read the bytes for each of that.

```
final var classes = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
try( final var inputStream = new JarInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream( bytes ) ) )
{
  var entry = inputStream.getNextJarEntry();
  while( nonNull( entry ) )
  {
    var buffer = new bytes [entry.getSize()];
    inputStream.read( buffer, 0, entry.getSize() );
    classes.add( buffer );
    entry = inputStream.getNextJarEntry();
  }
}
```

Ok, this is not tested, and of course there is none of the required  error handling, and perhaps you would prefer to store the class data in a map, with the class name as the key …

Have fun!

- [`ByteArrayInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)
- [`JarInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html)